# Implementing Job end notification listener in Hadoop

Tags: tomcat, servlets, hadoop, notifications, listener

I am trying to work on getting a notification once the job is completed. For which I am using the following link as a reference. I am unable to get it to work. I couldn't find much stuff on it on the internet. I am using tomcat as a means to establish a point for notification url where I am using a servlet.

http://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2013/09/18/hadoop-get-a-callback-on-mapreduce-job-completion/

This is the servlet which according to me is not supposed to work obviously because I am not calling it directly from another page where I should submit the parameters. Here I need a listener for getting the call from hadoop and then fetching the jobId and jobStatus which will be submitted to the servlet but I don't know how to achieve that.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Serv extends HttpServlet
{ 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException,IOException
    {
        String jobId=req.getParameter("jobId");
        String jobStatus=req.getParameter("jobStatus");
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw=res.getWriter();
        pw.println("JobId: \n"+jobId);
        pw.println("JobStatus: \n"+jobStatus);
        pw.close();
    }
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException,IOException
    {
        String jobId=req.getParameter("jobId");
        String jobStatus=req.getParameter("jobStatus");
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw=res.getWriter();
        pw.println("JobId: \n"+jobId);
        pw.println("JobStatus: \n"+jobStatus);
        pw.close();
    }
}
```

This is the part of code for notification in my Toolrunner run function.

```
conf.set("job.end.notification.url", "http://localhost:8080/Serv?jobId=$jobId&jobStatus=$jobStatus");                                 
conf.setInt("job.end.retry.attempts", 3);
conf.setInt("job.end.retry.interval", 1000);
```

I think there might be a lot more to do to get this working.

I tried the same with php as well changing the code accordingly.

**EDIT**
I got some part of it that I have to log the output in a file or somewhere else so that when the Servlet is called it should log the output to a file ie create a file with Job ID and Job Status. So I changed my Servlet code as follows but still there is no file created.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Serv extends HttpServlet
{ 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException,IOException
    {
        String jobId=req.getParameter("jobId");
        String jobStatus=req.getParameter("jobStatus");
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw=res.getWriter();
        pw.println("JobId: \n"+jobId);
        pw.println("JobStatus: \n"+jobStatus);
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("log.txt", "UTF-8");
        writer.println("Job ID : "+jobId);
        writer.println("Job Status : "+jobStatus);
        writer.close();
        pw.close();

    }
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException,IOException
    {
        String jobId=req.getParameter("jobId");
        String jobStatus=req.getParameter("jobStatus");
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw=res.getWriter();
        pw.println("JobId: \n"+jobId);
        pw.println("JobStatus: \n"+jobStatus);
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("log.txt", "UTF-8");
        writer.println("Job ID : "+jobId);
        writer.println("Job Status : "+jobStatus);
        writer.close();
        pw.close();
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is your servlet ever started? Is the `localhost:8080` the correct URL base?

Comment: Yes. If I try this in the browser http://localhost:8080/Serv?jobId=J1972&jobStatus=1 , it prints JobId: J1972 JobStatus: 1 .

Comment: is 'localhost' the relevant name in the context of the jobtracker? Can you try a FQDN instead? (of course make sure your server is also binding to real net address)

Comment: localhost is a relevant name for the jobtracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I finally did to get it working.
What I did earlier was some stupidity where I was trying to echo the output. It obviously seemed wrong to me but it didn't click to me that I have to log the output somewhere when the Servlet is called so I wrote the output to a file which worked.

The line `String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");` is important here as it sets the path to the Root directory else it gives permission denied to write log file.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Serv extends HttpServlet
{ 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException,IOException
    {
        String jobId=req.getParameter("jobId");
        String jobStatus=req.getParameter("jobStatus");
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw=res.getWriter();
        pw.println("JobId: \n"+jobId);
        pw.println("JobStatus: \n"+jobStatus);
        String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(path+"log.txt", "UTF-8");
        writer.println("Job ID : "+jobId);
        writer.println("Job Status : "+jobStatus);
        writer.close();
        pw.close();

    }
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException,IOException
    {
        String jobId=req.getParameter("jobId");
        String jobStatus=req.getParameter("jobStatus");
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw=res.getWriter();
        pw.println("JobId: \n"+jobId);
        pw.println("JobStatus: \n"+jobStatus);
        String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(path+"log.txt", "UTF-8");
        writer.println("Job ID : "+jobId);
        writer.println("Job Status : "+jobStatus);
        writer.close();
        pw.close();
    }
}
```